# saving snap svg canvas info to xml

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg, frontend

I'm using snap `svg` to draw some cool objects, I can change their properties (position and color) based on different inputs. Now I want to save the `svg` information (contained inside `div2`) for next session so that when I'll come back again, it would load the properties (postion and color) which I left from previous session.

I came to know that thus can be done using `xml`, but I don't know how! Can anybody help me to get this done? Also, if there's a better approach  to achieve the same, please do share.

Html code:

```
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    Blah! Blah! Blah! I want to save state of svg contained inside div2 only.
  </div>
  <div id="div2" height="1000px" width= "1000px">
    <svg id="svg" height="1000px" width= "1000px"></svg>
  </div>
 <div id="div1">
    Custom content, Blah Blah Blah again!
  </div>
</body>
```

Js code:

```
let paper = Snap("#svg-");

//drag handlers
function move(dx, dy, x, y, e) {
  let myset = this.data("mySet");
  myset.transform(this.data("mytransform")+'T'+Snap.snapTo(10,dx)+','+Snap.snapTo(10,dy));
}
function start(x, y, e) {
  let myset = this.data("mySet");
  myset.data("mytransform", this.transform());
}
function end(e) {
  let myset = this.data("mySet");
  myset.data("mytransform", this.transform());
}

let colors = ['#fa5', '#5fa', '#a5f', '#f5a', '#af5', '#5af'];
let counter = 0;

let obj = paper.g();
obj.add(paper.circle(500, 200, 50)).attr({fill: '#5af'});
obj.add(paper.rect(450, 250, 100, 100)).attr({fill: '#5af'});
obj.data('mySet', shp);
obj.drag(move, start, end);

obj.mousedown(e => {
  counter = (counter+1)%5;
  //change color on every click
  obj.attr({fill: colors[counter] });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the intended meaning of _save the svg information_, but if you mean the contents of SVG, you can get it by `innerHTML`...

Comment: My intention is save the state of ```svg``` object, i.e., when I load the above code for the first time, I'll get an object somewhere in between of screen and having color ```'#5af'```. Now, say, I dragged the object to top left of screen and color changes to ```'#fa5'``` (based on logic above). I want to save this state, i.e., if I would load it again, the object should be on top left (where I left it) and having color ```'#fa5'``` (the color which I left before saving the state of object)

Comment: Well it seems you need to implement a client-server API for it... or use the local storage

Comment: So there's nothing I can do to convert svg into xml on frontend? All can be done using client-server API?

Comment: You need a kind of persistent storage to keep your document state between the sessions. So it's either a server or a local storage. I don't know another option...